# Can we use a Relationship between 2 contacts, once in either direction?

Tags: relationships

Goal is to let X "favourite" Y and vice versa

But seems that civi won't let us do both between the same two contacts, ie we cannot let X favourite Y and at same time have Y favourites X.

Is it meant to be impossible to have 2 people with same relationship twice, once in either direction?

Comment: I can't think why it wouldn't allow this - what happens if you manually insert the 2nd in the civicrm_relationship table?

Comment: it works fine. Looks like there is some code in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/21cea480ee729320e15c71abdfa47f84a6bbdece/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php#L846 that is prohibiting this. so maybe an extension that provides a per relationship checkbox to permit (or prohibit depending which should be default) bi-directional relationships

Comment: We have had this fixed but i haven't had a chance to get the extension published or shared.

Comment: note to self: r10680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible and there is a patch to optionally allow bi-directional relationships in [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19630)

Answer (score 3):

Doing some research on your find using svn blame and svn log on the old svn repo, this appears to have been implemented as part of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-58, and the key comment is

i.e. if there is "Parent" relationship between 2 contacts then you cannot add another relationship "child " between them.

The code for this is also what's stopping adding the second "favourite". So it seems like the checking is too aggressive - makes sense to prevent the parent being a child of their spouse (except in some geographical regions where it might be true (grin)), but not your use-case.